# Show feedback to a user when loading content though ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm using the jquery tab plugin with the same results that are on jquery ui site ([link text](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ajax.html)).

The problem is that I want to change the tab label to something like "Loading" when the Ajax request is waiting for a response. How shall I achieve that?

**Edit:**

What I have now:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">User Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="/User/EditUser/<%: Model.Id %>">Edit</a></li>
    <li><a href="/User/Delete/<%: Model.Id %>">Delete AccountT</a></li>
  </ul>

   <div id="tabs-1">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("UserProfile", Model); %>
  </div>
</div>
```

and on javascript I just have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs({

    });
  });
</script>
```

What i want is to show a loading message inside the div of the active tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [widget doc](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax), ajax should work outside the box if your href is an actual link :

To customize loading message, you can use the `spinner` option :

> Fetch external content via Ajax for
>   the tabs by setting an href value in
>   the tab links.  While the Ajax request
>   is waiting for a response, the tab
>   label changes to say "Loading...",
>   then returns to the normal label once
>   loaded.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
            spinner: "<em>My Loading Msg</em>",
            ajaxOptions: {
                error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                    $( anchor.hash ).html(
                        "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                        "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The loading message don't go exactly where I was hoping but this is the cleaner way to achieve the result. * thumbs up *

Comment: While ajax is processing, your `li` containing the anchor gets the `ui-state-processing` class. With it you should be able to do a little more.

You should achieve to style related tab using :target css property, see http://kaioa.com/node/93 (not sure you can make it work with ajax loaded tabs thought).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just set the tab label to "loading" onclick and change it to whatever you want once you get a response back from your AJAX?

```
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $("#tab1").click(function() {
    $(this).val("Loading...");
        $.ajax({
        blablabla...
        success: function() {
        $("#tab1").val("Tab 1");
            }
        });
    });
```

This should give you an idea, obviously the function could be written better to act on each tab.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after already exists in the jquery ui for Tabs.

> The HTML content of this string is
>   shown in a tab title while remote
>   content is loading.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-spinner

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

From your example am I correct in assuming that you want to navigate to another page when the user clicks on either of the second two tabs, but you want a loading message to be displayed while you are waiting for the next tab to load?

If so, you could do it by keeping a loading message in the other tabs like so:

```
<input type="hidden" id="modelId" value="<%=Model.Id%>" />
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#tabs-1">User Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tabs-2">Edit</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tabs-3">Delete AccountT</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("UserProfile", Model); %>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Loading, please wait...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Loading, please wait...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And doing the redirection to your other pages in your javascript, doing it something like this:

```
$(document).ready(document_ready);

function document_ready()
{
    $("tabs").bind("tabsselect", onTabSelected);
}

function onTabSelected(event, ui)
{
    var modelId = $("#modelId").val();
    switch (ui.panel.id)
    {
        case "tabs-2":
            window.location.href = "/User/EditUser/" + modelId;
            break;
        case "tabs-3":
            window.location.href = "/User/Delete/" + modelId;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost perfect. The problem is that i don't want to open it on a new page. I want to show the html inside the tab body. example: When a user click on Edit, it should show the loading text (exactly like your solution) but then it should replace that with the  "/User/EditUser/" control.